# java script doesn't work in the angular component file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- the HTML page code. the script contains function for filter search of
  a table
- code copied from w3 school : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

  ```
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 



  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
  ```

  }

  Name
      Country
    
    
      Alfreds Futterkiste
      Germany
    
    
      Berglunds snabbkop
      Sweden
    
    
      Island Trading
      UK
    
    
      Koniglich Essen
      Germany

the component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-device',
  templateUrl: './current-device.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-device.component.css'],

})
export class CurrentDeviceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to use the ng model and write the javascript in component class